# Vertex id ignored when bulk loading data into Titan via BatchGraph

Tags: bulkinsert, titan, tinkerpop, tinkerpop-blueprint

When I start my bulk load process using `BatchGraph` on a `TitanGraph` object and [create vertices](https://github.com/sebschlicht/graphity-titan/blob/master/src/main/java/de/uniko/sebschlicht/graphity/titan/bootstrap/TitanBootstrapper.java#L80) I get annoying info messages:

```
73482 [de...TitanBootstrapper.main()] INFO com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx  - Provided vertex id [1425751377740] is ignored because vertex id setting is not enabled
```

I do not need vertex ids, since I have indexed vertex properties to identify a certain vertex.
Unfortunately `BatchGraph` only accepts calls to `addVertex` if I provide a vertex id and does not accept `null` values. Is there a way to avoid these messages?